# Creating a new user profile and simulating a login using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to write a Powershell script that creates a new user account (password and user name will be provided as inputs). I've been using the rather straightforward net use command to achieve this.

```
net user testuser testuserpwd /add
```

The problem I'm facing however is that this doesn't seem to create a user profile path or create a registry entry under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
```

with the SID. I haven't tried the new cmdlet `New-LocalUser`as my script has to be backward compatible i.e. it should work on machines using an older version of Powershell.

Is there any easy way to achieve this ?